# Unable to handle "HTTP Badstatus line" exception

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to handle `http.client.BadStatusLine: ''` exception.
I am on python3. My code is

```
import http.client

try:
    req = urllib.request.Request(url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Chrome/51'})
    html = urllib.request.urlopen(req).read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html,"html.parser")
    return soup
except http.client.HTTPException as eror:
    print("Boom")
```

but `httpException` is not in python3? [image: Figure]

I read [stackOverFloeQuestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8734617/python-django-badstatusline-error) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29981182/python-3-urllib-exception-http-client-badstatusline) but unable to catch it. Any help?

Comment: It is in the docs: https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.client.html#http.client.HTTPException

What is the actual error that you recieve?

Comment: @DeepSpace. I want to catch this exception. That is it. Red sign in the above picture is showing that `HTTPException` is not defined.

Comment: Copy-pasting your code doesn't reproduce that issue.

Comment: Copy-Pasting? Sorry . You did not understand the question. @Hans Then resolve it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make up your mind :-). You can either use `http.client` or `urllib.request`, but you should not use one and then try to catch errors from the other. If you want to stick with urllib.request, the class to catch is `urllib.error.HTTPError`.

Perhaps it may be more opportune in your case to use [Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/), which is a higher level http library.

Comment: I want to be specific to `BadStatusLine` Exception. Not whole `HTTPError`

Comment: While this is logically correct, it still doesn't explain why would `http.client.HTTPException` be not defined. Especially when copy-pasting OPs code doesn't reproduce the issue.

Comment: I think BadStatusLine is defined in httplib. So perhaps try `import httplib.BadStatusLine` and catch that error.